# Do I need to put css/js all in wwwroort folder in Asp.net Core? I am migrating from Older Mvc project

Tags: asp.net-core, wwwroot

I want to use js/files outside wwwroot folder. How to Do that?

Comment: Why not just move everything into `wwwroot`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can serve static files outside wwwroot.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyStaticFiles")),
        RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
    });
}
```

See [Serve files outside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

But why do you want this?

Comment: Like I said, I have migrating from mvc to MvcCore, and there are bunch of static files in that application. So I just though not to move those files. But is it good to move all files in wwwroot?  I just concern about number of files and sizes that's all.

Comment: it depends. But actually you need some modification in your project migration to .NET Core, maybe spend some time to bring it to standard Core architecture.